# How to Load assetBundle from android local folder?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to Load AssetBunddle form Android Folder from in Unity.
but it doesn't work...

I thought URL is wrong.

Changed URL many time, recommended or specification of Unity document but every case failed

Here is My Code.

```
    public string BundleURL;
    public int version;

    void Start()
    {
        CleanCache();
        BundleURL = "file://"+Application.persistentDataPath + " /BundleTest";

        StartCoroutine(LoadAssetBundle(BundleURL));
        version = 0;
    }
```

I thought BundleURL is wrong or has problem

```
    IEnumerator LoadAssetBundle(string BundleURL)
    {
        //BundleURL = "file://" + path ;
        GameObject obj;
        //ARLog.d ("LoadAssetBundle" + BundleURL);
        while (!Caching.ready)
            yield return null;
        using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(BundleURL, version))
        {
            yield return www;

            AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;

            String[] mPath = bundle.GetAllAssetNames();
            String bundleName = null;

            if (bundleName != null)
            {
                AssetBundleRequest request = bundle.LoadAssetAsync(bundleName, typeof(GameObject));
                yield return request;

                obj = Instantiate(request.asset) as GameObject;

                bundle.Unload(false);
                www.Dispose();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I want Instance Model in my Scene(from BundelTest Folder in Androind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an additional space there in

```
BundleURL = "file://"+Application.persistentDataPath + " /BundleTest";
```

in `" /BundleTest"`!

For paths in general you allways rather should use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) instead of manually concatenating strings:

```
    BundleURL = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,"BundleTest");
```

this makes sure that in the resulting path automatically the correct path separator (`/` or `\`) for the according atrget system is used.

Than note that `WWW` is obsolete and not that fast → you should have a look at [`AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync.html) there is an example of how to use it

```
    public void IEnumerator LoadBundle()
    {
        var bundleLoadRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "BundleTest"));
        yield return bundleLoadRequest;

        var myLoadedAssetBundle = bundleLoadRequest.assetBundle;
        if (myLoadedAssetBundle == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed to load AssetBundle!");
            yield break;
        }

        var assetLoadRequest = myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>("MyObject");
        yield return assetLoadRequest;

        GameObject prefab = assetLoadRequest.asset as GameObject;
        Instantiate(prefab);

        myLoadedAssetBundle.Unload(false);
    }
```

*If you prefer synchronous loading checkout [`AssetBundle.LoadFromFile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFile.html) instead.*

---

Another note in general: if you are using

```
using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(BundleURL, version))
{
    ....
}
```

you don't have to use `Dispose` as it is disposed at the and of the `using` block automatically.